# missing symbols that should be there

Tags: c, linux, symbols, shared-objects

I'm stumped. Here is the output of ld.

```
/usr/lib/libvisual-0.6/actor/actor_avs_superscope.so: undefined reference to `visual_mem_free'
/usr/lib/libvisual-0.6/actor/actor_avs_superscope.so: undefined reference to `visual_mem_malloc0'
```

Here are the macros:

```
#define visual_mem_new0(struct_type, n_structs)           \
    ((struct_type *) visual_mem_malloc0 (((visual_size_t) sizeof (struct_type)) * ((visual_size_t) (n_structs))))

#define visual_mem_malloc(size)     \
    visual_mem_malloc_impl (size, __FILE__, __LINE__, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__)

#define visual_mem_malloc0(size)    \
    visual_mem_malloc0_impl (size, __FILE__, __LINE__, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__)

#define visual_mem_realloc(ptr, size)   \
    visual_mem_realloc_impl (ptr, size, __FILE__, __LINE__, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__)

#define visual_mem_free(ptr)        \
    visual_mem_free_impl (ptr, __FILE__, __LINE__, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__)
```

Now it doesn't add up. One line's saying that visual_mem_free is missing, which is a macro. The other's saying that visual_mem_malloc0 is missing, but the code's actually calling visual_mem_new0, which suggests it sees visual_mem_new0.

```
priv = visual_mem_new0 (SuperScopePrivate, 1);

visual_mem_free (priv);
```

Any clues?

Edit: Bumping.. Maybe some fresh eyes can help?

Edit: By the way, I get no warnings/errors during compiling, nor linking.

Edit: Here's a couple of snippets from the preprocessor's output.

```
int lv_superscope_cleanup (VisPluginData *plugin)
{
 SuperScopePrivate *priv = visual_object_get_private ((((VisObject*) ((plugin)))));

 visual_mem_free_impl (priv, "actor_avs_superscope.c", 195, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

 return 0;
}
```

And:

```
 priv = ((SuperScopePrivate *) visual_mem_malloc0_impl (((visual_size_t) sizeof (SuperScopePrivate)) * ((visual_size_t) (1)), "actor_avs_superscope.c", 152, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__));
```

It looks like the macros are being expanded. I'm confused. Is `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` supposed to be expanded?

Interestingly enough, here's the output from strings.

```
$ strings .libs/actor_avs_superscope.so |grep malloc
visual_mem_malloc0_impl
visual_mem_malloc0
malloc
```

Chris: I'm just running `ld /usr/lib/libvisual-0.6/actor/actor_avs_superscope.so`.

And here's the output from nm:

```
$ nm actor_avs_superscope.o |grep malloc
         U visual_mem_malloc0_impl

$ nm actor_avs_superscope.o |grep free
         U visual_mem_free_impl
         U visual_palette_free_colors
```

Comment: What is the ld command line that is giving those errors?  Try running nm on all the .o files that go into actor_avs_superscope.so to see if you can figure out which source files are generating the references to these symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macros are handled during the pre-processing phase which comes before linking.  So if the link-editor is giving you warnings about macro names then the macros were not expanded.

To see the results of pre-processing, you can use the /E flag.  If your macros have been expanded, you would see the line:

```
visual_mem_free (priv);
```

changed to something like:

```
visual_mem_free_impl(priv, "filename.c", 32, "main");
```

**Update**

From your nm/strings output, the file actor_avs_superscope.o is not where the problem is.  What other object (.o) files and static archives (.a) are used to create actor_avs_superscope.so?  You should run nm on all of them in order to find who has the unexpanded macro name in them.

Comment: I compiled with -E and the output file looks like preprocessor work. I looked through and it appears the macros expanded. I'll update the question with what's in the file.

Comment: That's the only object file building the library. actor_avs_superscope.o

Comment: Oh wait, just found an .a file. That looks like the problem. (It's part of a larger package.)

Comment: Great.  If you use `nm -A`, nm will include the name of the object file each symbol is found in.

Answer (score 3):

Macros in C code don't result in symbols in compiled executables. Probably what is happening is that some code you are compiling didn't `#include` these macros, so the compiler inferred that they were functions, and compiled calls to them. You can use `-Wall` and `-Werror` to make calls to undefined functions fail to compile.

Comment: I had a couple of warnings. Got rid of those, but the symbols are still missing. Also, if the files weren't included, the call to `visual_mem_new0` would fail.

Comment: Yeah, I've used them, and they're no help in this situation. Like I said, I got rid of all the warnings/errors. It compiles with those flags, but I still have the initial problem mentioned in this question.

Answer (score 1):

Feels like it's not reading your `#define`s -- try printing a message inbetween them just to check.

Also check the order of compilation of your files; does the call to `visual_mem_new0` come after the `#define`s?

Answer (score 0):

Your first error is against the installed library, `/usr/lib/libvisual-0.6/actor/actor_avs_superscope.so` and it looks like you are looking at the local library in your project `strings .libs/actor_avs_superscope.so`. Try running strings against the one in `/usr/lib` and you'll probably see the issue.

I'd either Install your updated library version or put it's directory in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH when you run it, something like `$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./lib ./your_executable`.